# proximity sensor permission in android app

Tags: java, android, android-permissions, android-sensors

I am trying to design an app in Android Studio that uses the proximity sensor. I added the following code in the `manifest.xml` and it still doesn't ask for the permission when I launch the app:

```
uses-feature 
android:name="android.hardware.sensor.proximity" 
android:required="true"
```

Does anyone know why this happens? Is the proximity sensor always activated and therefore doesn't require a permission? Thank you!!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. If I have to guess now, it's because you're not asking the user for this permission.

Comment: Τhere's no need to request runtime permission from the user to use the proximity sensor. You can directly access the sensor in your app's code after you have declared the feature in your manifest.

Comment: Thank you very much for yur answers, it was really helpful!